# xCode localization export failed for shared framework with multiple destinations

Tags: xcode, localization

When exporting localization in xCode for a shared framework, the localization build fails with the error "Could not choose a single platform from the supported platforms iphoneos, iphonesimulator, watchos, watchsimulator of target"

Note that the shared target has multiple supported destinations = iPhone/iPad/Apple Watch.